# Irregular Verbs Conjugations in Strutz’s “501 German Verbs”

Tags: standard-german

In his book “501 German Verbs,” Strutz provides the conjugation of many (if not most) German irregular verbs. Some of the past participles of these irregular verbs are accompanied by an “ist” while the others (probably 80%) of the irregular verbs provided) aren’t. What is the purpose/function of the “ist”?

See pictures for reference.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: in past participle you sometimes need to extend your verb with a declinated "be" / "sein". Like "ich bin mit dem Flugzeug geflogen" (while "ich wurde vom Piloten geflogen" is also correct). As I have no rule at hand, I see no full answer possible.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm How would the meaning change if you used “wurde” instead of “bin”?

Comment: In my specific example the meaning changes from "I did sth." to "someone else did sth. for me" - from an activity of me to sth. passive I experienced. "Ich fliege" is an activity of me while "Ich werde geflogen" is the present for the wurde-example. I used it mainly to show that extention with "sein" is not all - and it has a different present.

Comment: Since the authorship and source are irrelevant (any verb list would do), I suggest to close the question and edit until that information disappears.

Answer (score 7):

The *ist* is probably meant to show you that those verbs go with ***sein*** in the perfect tenses. The German present and past perfect tenses use both ***sein*** and ***haben*** as auxilliaries. The most basic rule to decide which of these you need is this:

1. intransitive verbs (*those without an accusative object*) that denote a movement or a change of state use ***sein***
2. for everything else, we use ***haben***.

[Here's a slightly more in-depth overview for you.](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/perfekt.html#hilfsverben)

Comment: I've found some surprises, i.e. Verbs meaning movement or change and despite that they use *haben*, but it is rare. I've forgot them :-)

Comment: The verb *bewegen* (to move) is the most obvious counterexample.

Comment: _bewegen_ is either transitive (_etwas bewegen_: to move something else) or reflexive (_sich bewegen_: to move yourself). On the website I linked to, both of those cases are shown to be used with _haben_.

Answer (score 1):

I will second what @GrottenOlm said: The "ist" does indeed indicate the use of ***sein*** instead of ***haben*** as the auxiliary.

Since your original post is in English... English used to have this distinction too but lost it. You can still hear it though in certain phrases. The most notable one I can think of are the few opening lines of "Joy to the World"...

```
Joy to the World... The Lord **is** come.
```

In this case, "come" is the past participle (e.g. He comes, He came, He has come)... but, just like in German modernly, in the past you'd use "to be" with "to come" as the auxiliary.